# Comparing command line arguments reference return false while array of String return true

Tags: java, string, command-line-arguments, string-pool

Currently i am working with String manipulation and while doing demo i have found some different behaviour.

Below is my code.

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String str1 = "Hello";
    String str2 = "Hello";
    String str3 = new String("Hello");

    String strArray[] = {"Hello","Hello"};
    String strArray1[] = new String[] {"Hello","Hello"};

    System.out.println("str1==str2::  "+(str1==str2));
    System.out.println("str1==str3::  "+(str1==str3));

    System.out.println("strArray[0]==strArray[1]::  "+(strArray[0]==strArray[1]));
    System.out.println("str1==strArray[1]::  "+(str1==strArray[1]));

    System.out.println("strArray1[0]==strArray1[1]::  "+(strArray1[0]==strArray1[1]));
    System.out.println("str1==strArray1[1]::  "+(str1==strArray1[1]));

    System.out.println("args[0]==args[1]::  "+(args[0]==args[1]));
 }
```

}

And out put of above code is. I am running code passing command line arguments.

```
java HelloWorld Hello Hello
```

> str1==str2::  true
>   str1==str3::  false
>   strArray[0]==strArray[1]::  true
>   str1==strArray[1]::  true
>   strArray1[0]==strArray1[1]::  true
>   str1==strArray1[1]::  true
>   args[0]==args[1]::  false

Here i have two queries.

1. if i compare reference of String str1==str3 then it will return false because str3 is created using **new String** so that will not reside in String pool, So how **str1==strArray1[1] return true**??
2. strArray[0]==strArray[1] will return true, strArray1[0]==strArray1[1] also return true then why command line argument **args[0]==args[1] return false**??

Please guide.

Comment: You never showed us what values are being passed in as command line arguments.

Comment: Actually i am confused between String array which is created using new and command line arguments.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen He did actually

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen java HelloWorld Hello Hello

Comment: @ScaryWombat Didn't see that...it wasn't formatted as code :-(

Comment: This is not a dupe.. Atleast the second question isn't

Comment: @TheLostMind yup. i have doubt about that because i didnt clear out from all which string resides in string pool.

Comment: @Pratik - Did my answer clear that doubt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if i compare reference of String str1==str3 then it will return false
>   because str3 is created using new String so that will not reside in
>   String pool, So how str1==strArray1[1] return true??

`String strArray1[] = new String[] {"Hello","Hello"};` creates a new String array with a reference to the *same string* `"hello"` inside the array*.

> strArray[0]==strArray[1] will return true, strArray1[0]==strArray1[1]
>   also return true then why command line argument args[0]==args[1]
>   return false?

`args[0]==args[1]` returns `false`, because they are 2 *different* instances (not added to the String pool), they are like `new String()`. 
You can easily test this using :

```
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(args[0]));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(args[1]));
```

So, arguments passed to `main()` are **NOT** added to the **String constants pool**.

Comment: I will add here that String **literals** which are passed to any method other than `main` which are equal **do** get added to the String constants pool.

Answer (score 3):

*Don't* check references if all you want to compare is the content. That's why the `String` class provides the `equals()` method in the first place. The former tests for reference equality, the latter for value equality.

The way strings are handled internally has changed in the past, and may well change in the future. Using reference equality is relying on implementation details that you shouldn't really be relying on.

The whole *point* of encapsulation is to allow things to change under the covers without affecting client code. You should follow the "rules" so that you won't get bitten.

If you *really* want to understand how it works, you should read the Java Language Specification, available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). That's the standard for the language and anything not explicitly stated there is an implementation detail that should be irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks. but i want to know how it works and which Strings will resides in string pool.

Comment: @Pratik Why?  What will you do with that knowledge?  If it's just curiosity, fine.  But please do not use that knowledge when you're writing your programs, since as paxdiablo explained, it's an implementation detail and you should not write programs that rely on implementation details.

Comment: Yup thats only curiosity because want to know, How String works in different cases.