# Command line args :String objects created on heap?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, args

Please find the code snippet below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println(args[0]=="abc");
}
```

I am getting the output as false (believe me I am passing abc as command line args i.e. java Main abc from command line)
        Can somebody explain me the reason behind "false" in the output? what I could conclude is command line args are created on heap,but couldn't find the concrete reason/explanation for the same.I understand String comparison and difference between equals and ==.Are command line args not stored in String pool?

Comment: == checks equality of address of memory location and not the values using equals for string compares the value stored in the variable. If you use "abc".equals(args[0]) this will print true.

Comment: I understand that,but I dont find any rule which says that the command line args are created on the heap.

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar Did you find a rule that says they aren't?

Comment: Hi, I think the accepted answer of this question might give you the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248173/comparing-command-line-arguments-reference-return-false-while-array-of-string-re